# Simple jQuery + PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'update_data.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'asdfasd', //d,
    success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('jqXHR.responseText:  ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log('jqXHR.responseXML :  ' + jqXHR.responseXML);
        console.log('textStatus:   ' +  textStatus);
        console.log('errorThrown:   ' + errorThrown);
    },
    dataType : 'text'
});
```

Here is my 'update_data.php' :

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        echo "here!";
    } else {
        echo "failed jquery";
    }
?>
```

When I run the Ajax method, I get the following response in my console:

```
[]failed jquery
```

meaning update_data.php didn't get any POST request. '[]' is from json_econd($_POST), and 'failed jquery' is from the if/else.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use can also pass an array like this var myarray= JSON.stringify(arrayname);
then data: {data :myarray}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to pass data as below

```
 data : {'data':'asdfasd'},
```

if want to pass multiple parameters then

```
data : {'data':'asdfasd','param1':'value','param2':'value'},
```

or submit data of form

```
data : $( "formselector" ).serialize(),
```

**data parameter in ajax**

> Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the server. It
>   is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended
>   to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).

Read more about jquery ajax parameters [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

your sentence `echo json_encode($_POST);` is just response return back to your AJAX request. so the code under it do not work. Try comment this sentence and run again. I think you can see "here!" in console.

Answer (score 0):

You have doing two mistakes:

1:  In jquery you must send data like :
`data : {'data':'asdfasd'}`

2: In the 'update_data.php' : `json_encode` in the last of script

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use ajax the always pass the data as a key value pair inside curly braces as:

```
data = {'data':'asdfasd'}
```

- If you use this type of data passing then it will always work.
- Another thing is if you want to submit a full form data then try sending serialized data of form as:

> data = $('#form_id').serialize();

This will provide you all form data on your php page in $_GET -r $_POST whichever you have used as a method for ajax.